# how to deal with this integral equation

Tags: integration, integral-equations

I posted this question before in the Physics stack exchange, but it was recommended to post it better here.

While reading a paper I saw the following integral equation.

$\frac{1}{g} = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\prod_{\sigma}\frac{\mathrm{d}p_{\sigma}}{2\pi}) \frac{\delta(\Sigma_{\sigma}  p_{\sigma})}{(\prod_{\sigma} (1+\frac{2 \mathrm{sin}(p_{\sigma}/2)}{m}) -1)} \, ,\, \mathrm{with}\, \sigma = {1,2,3,4} $

But there was no solution given for it. To learn more about this integral equation, I would like to solve it. Sadly I don't even know how to begin/deal with this equation or more precisely with the integral itself. Hopefully someone can give me a hint or two.

cheers!

Comment: i guess you already have the starting point that the integral only has a non-zero component when $\sum_\sigma p_\sigma = 0$? so I guess you dealing with conservative (momenta? in different dimensions)

Comment: $p_1, ..., p_4$ are one dimensional momenta, which are conserved, indicated by the delta-function. should have mentioned that, sorry ...

Comment: can you solve the case of $\sigma=1$? it's quite straightforward

Comment: I tried to solve the trivial case $\sigma = 1$, but I did not succeed..

Comment: the integral reads in this case $\int_{\pi}^{-\pi}\frac{dp}{2 \pi}\frac{\delta(p)}{2\sin(p/2)/m}$

what is the effect of the delta function?

Comment: using the delta function ($\int dx f(x)\delta(x) = f(0)$), the solution should be $\frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{1}{ 2 sin(0/2)/m} $ = m/0, which is then undefined ..

Comment: in a very heuristic way i would say it's infinity and therefore $g=0$. You can make this more rigorous by introducing a small but finite $+\epsilon$ in the denominator,  which goes to zero at the end of the calculation

Comment: true, I agree with you. but I dont see how the trivial case can be connected to the original problem

Comment: indeed the integrals get more and more complicated, but using the delta constraint, at least the $\sigma=2$ case is doable. Let me know if you have some specific questions

Comment: Yeah the $\sigma = 2$ was doable. But the whole integration is pretty hard, even with the help of Mathematica am unable to solve it, because I am unable to simplify the term enough, to type it in Mathematica. One can easily do the integration using the deltafunction, which leads to replacing $p_4 = -p_1 - p_2 - p_3$ integrand. but afterwards this is just one big mess ..